# how to does auto refresh news feeds like facebook works?

Tags: facebook

Any idea how does the auto refresh news feeds like the facebook works? We are developing a site that is similar to facebook's news feeds features.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please consider narrowing the focus on your question down to something more specific, like 'should we use RSS feeds to do this thing we need done?'

Answer (score 0):

If by auto refresh you mean update while the user is on the page you could do it via web sockets, or with older technology just a simple ajax check every x number of seconds and then inject the content.